# How do I disable the "autosave warning screen" when I start a game?

Tags: ps3, system-mods

Whenever I start a game on PS3 I get a warning screen (something about not turning it off when it saving or something). Is there any way to turn it off without losing access to multi-player? maybe some software/hardware hacks?

It annoys me, because first I have to click ok on it, then I have to wait for game to load and click start, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, this is a "feature" of almost every game that autosaves, and I've never seen a way to turn it off.

I don't have a reference for this, but I've worked on a project that had similar features (automatic saving of files to a user's memory device) and we were required by the vendor to display a similar screen - it's a way to deflect the blame if the user does something silly, like pull the memory unit out or shut the device down when it's writing data.  That way, we could say "You were warned!" if/when you experience data loss.

I'd be willing to bet that Sony (and Microsoft, maybe Nintendo too) require such a screen to be present in a game that autosaves in order for said game to pass certification.

Comment: but they should put "i know this, stop bugging me" option, right?

Comment: @IAdapter No, the current industry standard is to require you to click through these kinds of screens.

Comment: case in point: unskippable DVD intro piracy warnings.

Comment: The 2D Adventures of Rotating Octopus Character (yes, that's a game's name) even has a bit of fun with this screen saying "Sorry about this screen, but rules are rules."